# Does half-level get added to damage in d&d 4th edition?

Tags: dnd-4e

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the half-level modifier contribute to damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8305/does-the-half-level-modifier-contribute-to-damage)

In 4th edition, half of your character's level is added to ability checks, does this mean that the damage from all of those abilities also increases?